# onclick vs. $.post how to isolate a button function vs. submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having this problem where a form is being submitted when it's not supposed to be submitted. This form is triggered by a button, however I'm clicking on a different button which performs a javascript math calculation... it seems that the onclick is being interpreted as a post?

How do I isolate a post eg. not submit the post unless I want to submit it?

this is the insert for php that is triggered by a different button.

```
<script>

function submitBill() {
var $id = "";
var $name = $('#name-of-bill').val();
var $cost = $('#cost-of-bill').val();
var $date = $('#due-date-of-bill').val();
$.post("insert-bill.php", {
'id':$id,
'name':$name,
'cost':$cost,
'date':$date }).done(function( data ) {

});
}
</script>
```

This is the button for the insert above

```
<button name="button-submit-new-bill" onclick="submitBill();">add bill</button>
```

This is the separate javascript math function that I'm trying to trigger.

```
// calculate weekly wage
function calculate() {
var hrs = document.getElementById('hours').value;
if(hrs>40){
var otHrs = hrs-40;
var regPay = 40*12;
var otPay = otHrs*18;
var pay = (regPay+otPay)*0.82;

var payM = +(Math.round(pay + "e+2") + "e-2");

alert(payM);

}else{
var pay = hrs*12*0.82;
var payM =  +(Math.round(pay + "e+2") + "e-2");

alert(payM);

}
}
```

This is the button that triggers the php insert above.

```
<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate();">go</button>
```

Comment: add `type=button` to the button, by default it acts as a `type=submit`

Comment: and if there are multiple submits? or do you not want to do that in general? or isolate by id?

Comment: you have a $.post inside your function submitBill() that is called from onlick via the button, it submits the post.

Comment: just add the button type to any button you don't want to be able to submit without javascript telling it to.

Comment: @Leo, I want to submit by button, but not every button should call that function that submits with $.post which is the problem I'm having, now I have the error "calculate is not a function"... hmm

Comment: your button name has the same name as the function, its not considered good pratice.

Comment: @Leo, that was it, thank you